# Library of old scanned manuscripts or handwritings in Spanish?

Tags: recursos, escritura-manuscrita

This is an example of such online libraries but in other languages:

[manuscripts in Persian or Arabic](http://unitproj.library.ucla.edu/dlib/minasian/list_mss.cfm)

May you offer some places that I can find **papers in Spanish ?**

Whether online (free) or for sale?

Comment: For a full list of resources, check [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674)

Comment: This is not really a language question but here is the largest archive (and library) of old publications in the Spanish-speaking world: https://www.mecd.gob.es/cultura/areas/archivos/mc/archivos/agi/servicios/biblioteca.html Click on Fondo Patrimonial for old maps and manuscripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found these:

- [PARES - Portal de Archivos Españoles](http://pares.mcu.es/)
- [BNE - Biblioteca Nacional de España](http://www.bne.es/)
- [Biblioteca Digital del Real Jardín Botánico](http://bibdigital.rjb.csic.es/spa/index.php)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot , also may you edit my **tags** so that they connect **my purpose** better ?